# Examples/types of xss attacks in php

Tags: php, security, xss, client-side

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site)
>   [Examples of XSS that I can use to test my page input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232405/examples-of-xss-that-i-can-use-to-test-my-page-input)

What are examples/types of client side xss attacks in php and how can I prevent them?

Comment: See: [Examples of XSS that I can use to test my page input?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232405/examples-of-xss-that-i-can-use-to-test-my-page-input), [What are the best practices for avoiding xss attacks in a PHP site](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/71328/what-are-the-best-practices-for-avoiding-xss-attacks-in-a-php-site), [How XSS attack really works?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3364427/how-xss-attack-really-works), http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=xss+php...

Comment: https://www.owasp.org/index.php/XSS_(Cross_Site_Scripting)_Prevention_Cheat_Sheet

Answer (score 0):

1. Plain text as HTML.
   When you forgot to escape plain text with htmlspecialchars.
   No prevention needed: just escape your variables when you use PHP in templates. Or use smarty/twig/etc.
2. HTML as HTML: when you allow users to create HTML(fckeditor/tinymce/plain HTML/etc).
   Use HTML sanitizer.
3. BB codes to HTML conversion.
   Do not use own regex-based parser, use only FSM-parsers.