# SOQL Injection in SFDC

Tags: api, rest, soap, salesforce

What is the best way to avoid SOQL Injection when querying salesforce through the APIs?
The two main APIs I am interested in are the SOAP and REST APIs.
My current methods are to never use any input from the user (which is impractical if they are searching for a Company Name) or encoding certain characters within the string.

However I saw that there was parameterisation within the APEX, so i was wondering if there was a similar way of doing it through the APIs.

Comment: https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexcode.meta/apexcode/pages_security_tips_soql_injection.htm and https://stories.salesforcecodex.com/2022/07/salesforce/what-is-soql-injection/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think all you really need to do is to make sure that the input, in this case the company name, is escaped properly. I am not aware of a parameterized way of building a query object for either of the API's.

However, if you needed to you could expose a custom web service method from within Salesforce so that you can pass the value in. Then from within the Salesforce Apex Code language you can parameterize the value using a syntax similar to below:

```
public Account[] queryCompany(string companyName) {
    return [SELECT Id FROM Account WHERE Name = :companyName];
}
```

Comment: i am currently trying to decide whether to have the Apex code on the SFDC instance to handle my requests, or whether to pass the queries directly. I guess having the Apex code requires more maintenence, but also adds extra safety against things like SQL Injection

Answer (score 1):

**Philosophical rant**

What are you after really :)

If your application should work same way accessed from different sources (Salesforce UI, PHP connector, some mobile applications) then it probably makes most sense to think about Apex like some stored procedures that will be reused. This means you'd be passing safe parameters to them.

If you plan to hand-craft queries & not rely on Apex too hard - maybe what you need is something like database.com or other cloud-based DB solutions?

**Actual answer**

I'm not aware of an out of the box way to pass separately the query command and separately the params to it (like bind variables/prepared statements) through APIs. Both REST and SOAP API give you what's essentially `Database.query()` within Apex. Sure, there are some differences like `retrieve()` command or `queryMore()` but that's the baseline.

What you could do is to either expose some commonly used searches with methods similar to what John proposed (bonus points for extra performance - they're precompiled) or build something generic?

```
List<sObject> runQuery(String query, List<List<String>> params){...}
```

If the `runQuery` will contain bind variables like `params[0]` it should work. Looks crazy and I didn't test it though ;) I'd say that bind variables are the best method. Alternative would be to escape user's input but SQL and XSS injections can become amazingly creative. Check [Examples of XSS that I can use to test my page input?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7232405/examples-of-xss-that-i-can-use-to-test-my-page-input) for a start (yes, I'm aware you asked about SOQL only).

As for actual SOQL injection: http://wiki.developerforce.com/page/Secure_Coding_SQL_Injection. Since "worst that can happen" is that users will search for more than they were supposed to (no way to convert SELECT into INSERT) escaping should be safe-ish...